# How do I show that there is no irreducible algebraic set $Y \subsetneq \mathbb{A}^n$ such that $Y \supsetneq X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Let $f \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be irreducible. The variety $X = V(f)$ is called an **irreducible hypersurface** in $\mathbb{A}^n$. How do I show that there is no irreducible algebraic set $Y \subsetneq \mathbb{A}^n$ such that $Y \supsetneq X$?

Comment: You mean " no irreducible algebraic set  $Y \subsetneq \mathbb{A}^n$..."

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming $k$ is algebraically closed. Suppose the statement is false and write $Y = V(f_1, \dots, f_m)$. Consider$$I(Y) = \{g \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n] : g(y) = 0 \text{ for all }y \in Y\}.$$Since $X \subset Y$, we must have$$\{f_1, \dots, f_m\} \subseteq I(Y) \subseteq I(V(f)) = \sqrt{f} = (f),$$where the first equality follows from the Nullstellensatz, and the last equality follows as $f$ is irreducible. Thus, we can factorize and write $f_i = g_if$ for some $g_i \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ for all $i \in \{1, \dots, m\}$. Now we have:$$Y = V(f_1, \dots, f_m) = V(g_1f, \dots, g_mf) = V(f)  \cup V(g_1, \dots, g_m).$$But then $Y$ is not irreducible, and thus we have a contradiction.